# render two different model errors in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, error-handling

I have a remote form, that essentially submits two forms in one. One for `Address` the other for `User` now what I'd like to do is render the errors in JSON.

I'm able to return the errors individually like this:

```
if current_user.errors.any? || !@address.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @address.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

now there's the case where they trigger an error on both User model and Address. How can I render both errors so `@address.errors` and `current_user.errors`. I've tried to merge them as hashes, but as they belong to ActiveModel::Errors it's unable to do so. An error usually returns like this if you inspect it:

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fbe094edda0 @base=#<Address id: nil, street_address: "Lorem ipsum", city: nil, state: nil, zip_code: "0000", country: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, latitude: 10.92876, longitude: 52.23023, trashed: false>, @messages={:zip_code=>["No zip code matches this"]}, @details={:zip_code=>[{:error=>:inclusion, :value=>"0000"}]}>
```

so what I'm trying to figure out is if there's a way to merge this into one, so I can just return that.

Comment: Is there any relation btween Address and User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
if current_user.errors.any? || !@address.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: {address_errors: @address.errors, current_user_errors: current_user.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Now you have a json response that is a hash with 2 entries: one for address_errors and one for current_user_errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
format.json { render json: { @address.errors, @user.errors }, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```